# Running a bash script with php from cron

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron, php

I have a script with a curl command in it for php to execute:

`/root/notify-down-script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "test" > file
curl -d "credentials=foobar" -d "title=$server down" https://notifi.it/api
```

I can execute from the command line:

```
/usr/bin/php -r "echo shell_exec(\"/root/notify-down-script.sh test\");"
```

which works perfectly. When I add to the cron:

```
*       *       *       *       *       /usr/bin/php -d safe_mode=Off -r "echo shell_exec(\"/root/notify-down-script.sh test\");"
```

This does not call the curl (does call the `echo`). This is all ran as root. I have tried to catch the output (> /tmp/curl.log) of the curl in the script but nothing happens. I have tried to do the full path of the curl. I am completely lost. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is convoluted. Any reason not to just run your script directly, without PHP, as `/root/notify-down-script.sh`? Also, check cron logs for errors, or set `MAILTO` to an e-mail address to hopefully get an error report.

Comment: This is just an example of where it goes wrong. Imagine a massive php script and the exec is somewhere within. I have been trying to solve this all day!!

Comment: I also know 100% the script is still exectued because I have another line like 'echo "hello" > file' which is executed

Comment: OK. Can you try running your script with tracing enabled (`set -x` as the first line, or run with `bash -x`) and write the output of that somewhere? That should show how far the execution goes.

Comment: is PHP depending on an environment variable that you set but that cron does not? check for overrides with `set|grep ^PHP`. Also, you mention a curl.log but I don't see a reference to it in your code. Can you check the cron log for evidence of it being called?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the full path to curl call inside your script, like this:

> /usr/bin/curl -d "credentials=foobar" -d "title=$server down" https://notifi.it/api

Comment: Please see question. I have already tried that!